# How does SO implement the diff efficiently?

Tags: discussion

How does it check if the answer is modified or not?

Comment: That's two different questions, by my count.

Comment: You're allowed to ask more than one.

Comment: All right, let me try again: That's two **different** questions, by my count.

Comment: You **are** asking programming questions on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost 100% sure that they use the [Longest Common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm to find changes.

Comment: Citation needed!

Answer (score 1):

Jeff talks about it in a blog post:

[Mixing Oil and Water: Authorship in a Wiki World](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001222.html)

He provides a link to the paper: [An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and its Variations](http://xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf) (pdf) and a [C# Implementation](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/DiffDoku.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

W.R.T. modified or not -- my money is on a hash of the before text compared to a hash of the edited text.  If they're the same, it wasn't edited (or more accurately "statistically unlikely it was edited").

I can't speak for the diff itself.

Comment: You think hash is for free?

Comment: We can hope...  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> How does it check if the answer is modified or not?

Each revision is stored in a PostRevision table, something along the lines of..

```
PostId    PostBody        PostCreatedAt
1234      My answer is... 2009-01-01 00:00:01
1234      Edited answer.. 2009-01-02 08:04:01
```

To find out if a question has been edited (and if it needs to show a link to the revisions page), you would just do something like `SELECT count(*) FROM PostRevision WHERE PostID=1234`

For efficiency, I imagine this data is denormalised, so there would be a `NumberOfTimesEdited` column in the Posts table